Postgis only-two-points LINESTRING performance
i have an MVT service based on a large  only-two-points LineString postgis table(because of bussiness needs, it can't be merged into multilinestring),when it was rendered on the web,it shows low performance on my no-gpu computer, maybe it's because i can't simplify(using ST_Simplify) the  only-two-points LineString geometry. So, is there any efficient way to serve an MVT service with LineString data and render it on a low-performance computer?
here is my code:
const sql = `
SELECT
ST_AsMVT (q, '${lid}', 4096, 'geom') as a
FROM
(
  SELECT${res}, ST_AsMvtGeom (
    st_simplify(ST_Transform(${layerPublishInfo.getModelParam()}, 3857), ?),
    lsy_bboxxyz3857 (?, ?, ?),
    4096,
    256,
    true
  ) AS geom
  FROM
  "${layerPublishInfo.getLayerId()}"
  WHERE
  ST_Intersects (
    ST_Transform(${layerPublishInfo.getModelParam()}, 3857),
    lsy_bboxxyz3857 (?, ?, ?)
  )
) AS q;
`


You need to find the bottleneck: 1) generating the tiles (Postgres) 2) serving the tiles (Network) or 3) rendering the tiles (client).

That being said, make sure you have a usable spatial index, i.e. on ST_Transform(${layerPublishInfo.getModelParam()}, 3857),, not only on the geometry column.

could you use raster tiles (WMTS) at smaller zoom levels to avoid sending too much data to the client?

@JGH I think the biggest bottleneck is in the client rendering, because of my non-gpu computer

@lan Turton Maybe it's a good idea, but it will really complicate the application's architecture.
